# three fluid divs, center div contains a form input

Tags: html, css

Tried various methods to get this to work, however my end result is never as expected. I have three divs in a container stretching the width of the screen, the center div contains a form/input. The idea is to have the center div resize with the form when the window resizes.

```
<div style="width:100%;">
  <div style="width:33%; float:right">Contact|Twitter|Pintrest</div>
  <div style="width:33%; float:left;">Home|Blog|Fishing</div>
  <div style="margin-right:33%; float:left;"><form><input style="width:100%;"></form></div> 
</div>
```

This is just a brief example to show what I'm attempting. Appreciate any help.

Comment: what do you mean by **center div resize with the form when the window resizes**

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/45sn2xz8/) what you want? Your Question is bit unclear.

Comment: Apologies, the left and the right div contain text, the middle div contains an input. When I resize my browser, the center div should adjust to make up for lost space. The issue isn't getting the divs to resize properly, its getting the input to resize correctly with the center div.

Answer (score 0):

Set `width` to the center element too, see the example code below (I put your inline styles to CSS for the better reading example):

```
<style>
    #left {background: #333; width: 33%; float: left;}
    #right {background: #666; width: 33%; float: right;}
    #center {background: red; float: none; width: 33%; margin: 0; display: inline-block;}
</style>

<div>
  <div id=right>Contact|Twitter|Pintrest</div>
  <div id=left>Home| Blog|Fishing</div>
  <div id=center><form><input style="width:100%;"></form></div> 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qkpnxwpa/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with position:absolute. The advantage of this is that you can use absolute position inside each section. The CSS would look like this

```
section{
  width:calc(100% / 3);
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
#left{
  left:0;
  background-color:red;
}
#center{
  left:calc(100% / 3);
  background-color:blue;
}
#right{
  left:calc(100% / 3 * 2);
  background-color:green;
}
```

Using box-sizing:border-box means you can give each element a border without messing up the alignment.